# How to Check is Internet Available without creating overhead in Unity3d

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, internet-connection

I need to check if the internet is avaiable or not in my games so that I can make a decision. There are two different types of decision when internet is working and when internet is not working. I found a way but it creates an overhead for the cpu. Currently I am using this type of solution. Is there a better way to check either internet is avaiable or not?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class DeviceConnected : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const bool allowCarrierDataNetwork = false;
    private const string pingAddress = "8.8.8.8"; // Google Public DNS server
    private const float waitingTime = 2.0f;
    public Text txtInternetConnectStatus;
    private Ping ping;
    private float pingStartTime;
    private bool isInternetAvailable = false;

    public void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("OnStartCheck", 0f,3.0f);

    }

    public void OnStartCheck()
    {
        bool internetPossiblyAvailable;
        switch (Application.internetReachability)
        {
            case NetworkReachability.ReachableViaLocalAreaNetwork:
                internetPossiblyAvailable = true;
                break;
            case NetworkReachability.ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork:
                internetPossiblyAvailable = allowCarrierDataNetwork;
                break;
            default:
                internetPossiblyAvailable = false;
                break;
        }
        if (!internetPossiblyAvailable)
        {
            InternetIsNotAvailable();
            return;
        }
        ping = new Ping(pingAddress);
        pingStartTime = Time.time;
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (ping != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hi");
            bool stopCheck = true;
            if (ping.isDone)
            {
                if (ping.time >= 0)
                    InternetAvailable();
                else
                    InternetIsNotAvailable();
            }
            else if (Time.time - pingStartTime < waitingTime)
                stopCheck = false;
            else
                InternetIsNotAvailable();
            if (stopCheck)
                ping = null;
        }
    }



    private void InternetIsNotAvailable()
    {
        if (isInternetAvailable == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("No Internet :(");
            txtInternetConnectStatus.text = "No Internet :(";
            isInternetAvailable = true;
        }
    }

    private void InternetAvailable()
    {
        if (isInternetAvailable==true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Internet is available! ;)");
            txtInternetConnectStatus.text = "Internet is available! ;)";
            isInternetAvailable = false;

        }

    }


    public void OnClickShowMediationSuite()
    {
        ShowAds.instance.ShowMediationSuite();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without overhead? I'm pretty sure the only thing that cast no overhead is by doing nothing at all. You will have to explain more clearly what you mean with this.

Answer (score 0):

This was written on the fly without a Unity so there could be some errors. This code now uses `StartCorutine` instead of `InvokeRepeating` and the repeating parts are now loops inside the function using `yield return WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenChecks);` for long delays and `yield return null;` for single frame delays.

```
public class DeviceConnected : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const bool allowCarrierDataNetwork = false;
    private const string pingAddress = "8.8.8.8"; // Google Public DNS server
    private const float waitingTime = 2.0f;
    private const float timeBetweenChecks = 3.0f;
    public Text txtInternetConnectStatus;
    private float pingStartTime;
    private bool isInternetAvailable = false;

    public void Start()
    {
        //Start out with the assumption that the internet is not available.
        InternetIsNotAvailable();

        StartCoroutine(InternetCheck());

    }

    public IEnumerator InternetCheck()
    {
        //If you want it to stop checking for internet once it has a successful connection, 
        //just remove "while (true)" loop
        while (true)
        {
            bool internetPossiblyAvailable = false;
            while (!internetPossiblyAvailable)
            {
                switch (Application.internetReachability)
                {
                    case NetworkReachability.ReachableViaLocalAreaNetwork:
                        internetPossiblyAvailable = true;
                        break;
                    case NetworkReachability.ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork:
                        internetPossiblyAvailable = allowCarrierDataNetwork;
                        break;
                    default:
                        internetPossiblyAvailable = false;
                        break;
                }
                if (!internetPossiblyAvailable)
                {
                    InternetIsNotAvailable();
                    //Wait to check again.
                    yield return WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenChecks);
                }
            }

            Ping ping = new Ping(pingAddress);
            pingStartTime = Time.time;

            Debug.Log("Hi");
            bool stopCheck = true;

            while (!ping.isDone && Time.time - pingStartTime < waitingTime)
            {
                //Wait one frame;
                yield return null;
            }

            if (ping.isDone && ping.time >= 0)
                InternetAvailable();
            else
                InternetIsNotAvailable();

            //Wait to check again.
            yield return WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenChecks);

        }
    }
    private void InternetIsNotAvailable()
    {
        //Only log when we are going from true to flase.
        if (isInternetAvailable != false)
        {
            Debug.Log("No Internet :(");
            txtInternetConnectStatus.text = "No Internet :(";
            isInternetAvailable = false; //This was changed from true to false.
        }
    }

    private void InternetAvailable()
    {
        //Only log when we are going from false to true.
        if (isInternetAvailable != true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Internet is available! ;)");
            txtInternetConnectStatus.text = "Internet is available! ;)";
            isInternetAvailable = true; //This was changed from false to true
        }

    }

    public void OnClickShowMediationSuite()
    {
        ShowAds.instance.ShowMediationSuite();
    }
}
```

This hopefully will have a lower overhead cost. You could even replace the `yield return null` with a `yield return WaitForSeconds(0.5f);` so it waits 500 milliseconds to check to see if the ping completed yet. At 30 fps that would mean you would only have a tiny overhead cost to check to see if the ping is done once every 15 frames.